# Clase 'Conexión' PDO no se ejecuta

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estoy tratando de probar una conexión PHP y Mysql para **login** utilizando PDO y al tratar de imprimir el resultado con con `print_r` el archivo 'login.php' ni siquiera se abre. A continuación el código:

conexion.php

```
<?php
class Conexion{
public static function Conectar(){
define('servidor','localhost:8080');
define('nombre_bd','name');
define('usuario','root');
define('password','');

$opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');

try{
  $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".servidor.";dbname=".nombre_bd, usuario, password, $opciones);
  return $conexion;
}catch(Exception $e){
  die("El error de conexión es: ".$e->getMessage());
  }
 }
}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
include_once 'conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();

print_r($conexion);
```

Comment: Saludos. Da una mirada la forma en que se invoca a lo que declaras `static` (ver https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.static.php ) así mismo te falta el `return` puede salgan otros mensajes de error pero en su momento se checa a que se deben.

Comment: @BetaM no me arroja error, sencillamente al tratar de abrir el archivo `login.php` que es donde añadí el archivo conexion.php, se cicla y no se abre.

Comment: Como te ha dicho @RobertoLeOr, mira cómo invocar un método estático... No puedes acceder a él mediante un objeto instanciado, si no que debes acceder a él mediante la clase: `Conexion::conectar()`

Comment: @BeaM Así es, es funcional por que es un código que ya use en otro equipo pero estoy añadiendo el puerto por que mi servidor local lo tengo en 8080

Comment: @BetaM pero tenías razón, he quitado el puerto 8080 dejando únicamente localhost y ha funcionado. GRACIAS

Answer (score 1):

Ha funcionado definiendo la variable de host solo con `localhost` sin usar **8080** y ha quedado:

```
define('servidor','localhost');
```